# How to replace/insert a subdocument in nested array in MongoDB in just one command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `persons` with an array of `answers`:

```
[{ _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf3272ef"), "name": "Mike", 
"answers": [ { "questionId": 118, "aaa": "xyz", "bbb": "xyz" } ] },
{ _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf3272ab"), "name": "John", 
"answers": [ { "questionId": 101, "aaa": "xyz", "ccc": "xyz" } ] },
{ _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf327212"), "name": "Els", 
"answers": [ { "questionId": 101, "aaa": "qrt", "ccc": "qrt" } ] },
{ _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf32724d"), "name": "Josefien", 
"answers": [ 
    { "questionId": 109, "sss": "xyz", "ttt": "xyz" },
    { "questionId": 110, "nnn": "xyz", "mmm": "xyz" },
    { "questionId": 111, "kkk": "xyz", "lll": "xyz" },
]}]
```

Now I have a new `answer` from one `person`. When the `questionId` already exists I want to replace the whole subdocument `answer`. If not I want to add a new subdocument `answer`.

I tried this, but doesn't work, giving an error if it's a new subdocument:

```
db.persons.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf3272ef"), "answers.questionId": answer.questionId },
    { $set: { "answers.$": answer } },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

This is working fine:

```
db.persons.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf3272ef") },
    { $pull: { answers: { questionId: answer.questionId } } }
);   

db.persons.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf3272ef") },
    { $addToSet : { answers: answer } }
)
```

But is there a way to do this in just one command?

Imagine that the `persons` collection has 10 millions of documents in real life. Also every person gives many new answers. In that case one transaction above two would be highly preferred.

Comment: whatever you have quoted would be the cleanest possible answer to your question.

Comment: @RahulRaj: If the collection `persons` has millions of documents this seems to be a very inefficient way of doing because of two transactions. Not?

Comment: can you post sample data set with more than 1 document?

Comment: @RahulRaj: I changed my post on your request. Thanks for willing to help me !

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
db.persons.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5abd0550dcc44451cf3272ef"), "answers.questionId": answer.questionId },
    { $set: { 'answers.$': answer }}
);
```

Comment: It's not working unfortunately. Updating "yes", adding new document "no"